# Group Static const in Dart Class

Tags: class, dart, static, grouping

I have a Icon class known as `KIcons`. inside this class I have 2 types of icons. One is `Solid` and other is `Outlined`. Now I want to access it as below. How to do so ?
Expected output : `KIcons.solid.back_arrow`
reason for this is, when I type `KIcons.solid` I should only get the list of the `const` defined under this `grouping` as both will have same and different icons. How should I achieve this?

currently I have everthing under one roof with naming like `solidArrowLeft` accessibile as `KIcons.solidArrowLeft`.

Code:

```
class KIcons {
  // solid
  static const String solidArrowLeft = "assets/icons/solid/arrow-left.svg";
  static const String solidArrowRight = "assets/icons/solid/arrow-right.svg";
  static const String solidArrowTop = "assets/icons/solid/arrow-Top.svg";
  static const String solidArrowBottom = "assets/icons/solid/arrow-bottom.svg";
  static const String solidChevronLeft = "assets/icons/solid/chevron-left.svg";
  static const String solidChevronRight =
      "assets/icons/solid/chevron-right.svg";
  static const String solidChevronTop = "assets/icons/solid/chevron-Top.svg";
  static const String solidChevronBottom =
      "assets/icons/solid/chevron-bottom.svg";
  static const String solidArrowCircleLeft =
      "assets/icons/solid/arrow-circle-left.svg";
  static const String solidArrowCircleRight =
      "assets/icons/solid/arrow-circle-right.svg";
  static const String solidArrowCircleTop =
      "assets/icons/solid/arrow-circle-Top.svg";
  static const String solidArrowCircleBottom =
      "assets/icons/solid/arrow-circle-bottom.svg";

  // outlined
  static const String outlineArrowLeft = "assets/icons/outline/arrow-left.svg";
  static const String outlineArrowRight =
      "assets/icons/outline/arrow-right.svg";
  static const String outlineArrowTop = "assets/icons/outline/arrow-Top.svg";
  static const String outlineArrowBottom =
      "assets/icons/outline/arrow-bottom.svg";
  static const String outlineChevronLeft =
      "assets/icons/outline/chevron-left.svg";
  static const String outlineChevronRight =
      "assets/icons/outline/chevron-right.svg";
  static const String outlineChevronTop =
      "assets/icons/outline/chevron-Top.svg";
  static const String outlineChevronBottom =
      "assets/icons/outline/chevron-bottom.svg";
  static const String outlineArrowCircleLeft =
      "assets/icons/outline/arrow-circle-left.svg";
  static const String outlineArrowCircleRight =
      "assets/icons/outline/arrow-circle-right.svg";
  static const String outlineArrowCircleTop =
      "assets/icons/outline/arrow-circle-Top.svg";
  static const String outlineArrowCircleBottom =
      "assets/icons/outline/arrow-circle-bottom.svg";
}
```

An Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
class KIcons {
  // solid
  static const _KIconsSubType solid = _KIconsSubType('solid');
  
  // outlined
  static const _KIconsSubType outlined = _KIconsSubType('outlined');
}

class _KIconsSubType {
  final String arrowLeft;
  final String arrowRight;
  final String arrowTop;
  final String arrowBottom;
  final String chevronLeft;
  final String chevronRight;
  final String chevronTop;
  final String chevronBottom;
  final String arrowCircleLeft;
  final String arrowCircleRight;
  final String arrowCircleTop;
  final String arrowCircleBottom;

  const _KIconsSubType(String type)
      : arrowLeft = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-left.svg",
        arrowRight = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-right.svg",
        arrowTop = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-Top.svg",
        arrowBottom = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-bottom.svg",
        chevronLeft = "assets/icons/$type/chevron-left.svg",
        chevronRight = "assets/icons/$type/chevron-right.svg",
        chevronTop = "assets/icons/$type/chevron-Top.svg",
        chevronBottom = "assets/icons/$type/chevron-bottom.svg",
        arrowCircleLeft = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-circle-left.svg",
        arrowCircleRight = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-circle-right.svg",
        arrowCircleTop = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-circle-Top.svg",
        arrowCircleBottom = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-circle-bottom.svg";
}
```

Example if you have some differences between the types:

```
class KIcons {
  // solid
  static const _KIconsSolid solid = _KIconsSolid();

  // outlined
  static const _KIconsOutlined outlined = _KIconsOutlined();
}

class _KIconsSubTypeCommon {
  final String arrowLeft;
  final String arrowRight;
  final String arrowTop;
  final String arrowBottom;
  final String chevronLeft;
  final String chevronRight;
  // final String chevronTop;
  final String chevronBottom;
  final String arrowCircleLeft;
  final String arrowCircleRight;
  final String arrowCircleTop;
  final String arrowCircleBottom;

  const _KIconsSubTypeCommon(String type)
      : arrowLeft = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-left.svg",
        arrowRight = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-right.svg",
        arrowTop = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-Top.svg",
        arrowBottom = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-bottom.svg",
        chevronLeft = "assets/icons/$type/chevron-left.svg",
        chevronRight = "assets/icons/$type/chevron-right.svg",
        // chevronTop = "assets/icons/solid/chevron-Top.svg",
        chevronBottom = "assets/icons/$type/chevron-bottom.svg",
        arrowCircleLeft = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-circle-left.svg",
        arrowCircleRight = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-circle-right.svg",
        arrowCircleTop = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-circle-Top.svg",
        arrowCircleBottom = "assets/icons/$type/arrow-circle-bottom.svg";
}

class _KIconsSolid extends _KIconsSubTypeCommon {
  final String chevronTop;

  const _KIconsSolid()
      : chevronTop = "assets/icons/solid/chevron-Top.svg",
        super("solid");
}

class _KIconsOutlined extends _KIconsSubTypeCommon {
  const _KIconsOutlined() : super("outlined");
}
```

Comment: 3 questions I have. one what is this call and where can I read more as I am still leaning the basics to do this stuff. as you have made this icon varaiable available but in case we don't have same icon what shall be done/ e.g. `solid` have `chevronTop` but `outlined` don't have `chevronTop`. for this will I have to create new class entierly for outline as we don't need to display what is not present under those icons case.

Comment: @princeoo7 Well, my first example is really just a matter of using constructor and recognize when we can simplify stuff and use a parameter instead of rewrite most of the same code twice. My second example uses inheritance so we can have a common class which we reuse and then we have specific sub-classes we then use to add more stuff we need.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance and explaination :) really appriciate the help :)

Comment: instead of `final` I need the varaibles to be `const` but getting ```The constant 'opacity' must be initialized.Try adding an initialization to the declaration.``` any suggestions.

Comment: @princeoo7 All the variables in my example can be used as const values (they are all final in an class with a const constructor). I think you should make a new question where you can show your code with the error and try explain in more details what you are trying to achieve.